# Error in html_table.xml_node(., header = FALSE) : html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

this is the code I have written to extract the table present on this webpage given below but i am not able to extract the table .

problem code line -

```
html_node("#embed") %>% #embed is I have selected using selectorgadget.
```

snippet:

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
google <-read_html("https://data.gov.in/major-indicator/gross-enrolment-ratio-higher-education")
google %>%  
html_node("#embed") %>%
html_table(header=FALSE)
```

please help me .

Comment: Perhaps this working code would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293830/specifying-column-class-in-html-tablervest

Comment: by "table" you mean when you click on the "Data" button/link?

Comment: That site is powered by an API and all of the vis & table data is generated dynamically. Rather than reverse-engineer how the HTML presentation layer does what it does, just use the [API they provide](https://data.gov.in/help/how-use-datasets-apis) to get the data you want (esp since the site _uses the same API to generate the views_).